# Foreground Service next to normal Service

Tags: android, service, background

I wander if Android only "guarantees" to keep a service alive if it is running as a foreground service. But what if I run two services next to each other in the same process one as a foreground one as a normal service. Does the second service gets the same guarantees?

```
main process:
  ForegroundService - Service with foreground flag
  MyService         - Normal Service

low memory event -> 
  Scenario 1:
  keep ForegroundService and keep MyService

  Scenario 2:
  keep ForegroundService and kill MyService
```

Note: 
I did some investigation on Android 7 and 5 and in both cases a single running foreground service would keep all services within the process alive if memory runs low and starts killing other memory consumers. 
But if Android runs low, it will kill the whole process and not just remove single processes.

Answer (score 0):

if your define process for each service in manifest then it will take guarantee

```
<service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true" android:process="myporcee"
        android:exported="true"></service>
```

Comment: This is not really an answer to my question. Android runs both services already in the same process (the main process) , but it could still force stop one of the other none-foreground services.

Comment: So other solution is restart service on some periodic time or alert uses that please do not use any Cleaner or anti virus app

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says, that it may kill ordinary Service, but not the one, started as foreground. If you want to persist both services, you can bind 
ordinary Service to foreground service so both services will have the same priority.